# Moment Generating Functions with Nonlinear Transformation

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

So I am rusty on moment generating functions.  I found this problem (and solution) in old notes, and I can't remember why it works. The problem is to find the moment generating function of $Y$ when $Y = (X-3)^2$ and $X \sim N(0,1)$.

The solution:

$E(e^{t(X-3)^2}) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{t(x-3)^2} \frac{-e^{x^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} dx \rightarrow Simplify$

So my intuition was to first transform X, and then find the MGF of Y in the usual way, which is undoubtedly more complicated.  I know we can find the MGFs of linear transformations of variables fairly easily, but why can we do this for this situation?

Comment: The solution you present is just the definition of the MGF for $Y = (X-3)^2$. You could add: $\mathbb{E}[e^{tY}] = \mathbb{E}[e^{t(X-3)^2}]$ to be explicit.

Comment: You can get displayed equations by enclosing them in double instead of single dollar signs.

Comment: The subtle point here is the [Law of the Unconscious Statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g:\mathbb R\to[0,\infty)$ is a measurable function then we have for any random variable $X$
$$
\mathbb E[g(X)] = \int_\Omega g\circ X\ \mathsf d\mathbb P = \int_{\mathbb R} g\ \mathsf d(X_*\mathbb P),
$$
where $X_*\mathbb P = \mathbb P\circ X^{-1}$, i.e. $X_*\mathbb P(B) = \mathbb P(X^{-1}(B)) = \mathbb P(X\in B)$ for any Borel set $B$. If $X_*\mathbb P$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure $\mu$, that is $\mu(B)=0\implies X_*\mathbb P(B)=0$, written $X_*\mathbb P\ll \mu$, then by the Radon-Nikodym theorem $X$ has a density $f_X$ such that $X_*\mathbb P(B) = \int_B f_X\ \mathsf d\mu$ for all Borel sets $B$. In this case we have
$$
\mathbb E[g(X)] = \int_{\mathbb R}g(x)f_X(x)\ \mathsf dx.
$$

In this case $g(x) = e^{t(x-3)^2}$ is a continuous function of $f$, so 
$$
\mathbb E[g(X)] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)f_X(x)\ \mathsf dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{t(x-3)^2}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac12 x^2}\ \mathsf dx = \frac{e^{\frac{9 t}{1-2 t}}}{\sqrt{1-2 t}}, \quad t<\frac12.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Although I believe the other answer is correct and more thorough, @Robert Israel gave me the hint I needed, which was used in the last line of Math1000's answer.